# rbenv Install Ruby Failing on Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, passenger, rbenv

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 trying to get a Rails 4 application running with Passenger.  I'm attempting to use rbenv to configure my ruby/rails environments.

I've installed rbenv via apt (`sudo apt-get install rbenv`). I have access to all of the rbenv tools (install, which, etc.) The issue comes when passenger tries to run the rails app. I suspect it is simply that the passenger service cannot use the local rubies, as a service doesn't have a home folder, but I'm shooting in the dark there.

The specific error I am getting is: `/usr/local/bin/rbenv-install: line 117: rbenv-hooks: command not found`

This happens in passenger or if I just run `rbenv install 2.1.0` (or whatever version)

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was really simple.

When running the Passenger Apache Module, there are a number of [configuration variables](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger) you can add to your virtual hosts file.  Somehow I missed the documentation first go around.  The solution ended up being as simple as adding this line to my vhosts file:

```
PassengerRuby /home/{user}/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
```

All is good now, hope this helps someone else.